# In Dax, how can I get value from multiple columns with multiple criteria?

Tags: dax, powerquery

I am just a beginner in Dax language.
I googled it a lot to find solution, but failed.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Here are the two tables examples and there is no relation between them. ( I am using power query and power pivot)
I need to get sales location visitor from another table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwEN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcfsA.png)

| Branch | Date | Item | QTY | Sales Location | Visitor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA. | 2021.01.01 | A. | 23 | 1st floor | ???? |
| Canada | 2021.01.02 | B. | 44 | 2nd floor | ???? |

| Date | USA's 1st floor visitor | USA's 2nd floor visitor | Canada's 1st floor visitor | Canada's 2nd floor visitor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.01.01 | 5435 | 664 | 2342 | 4532 |
| 2021.01.02 | 5345 | 345 | 2234 | 342 |

I tried to use IF and Lookupvalue, but it shows errors.
Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Power Query to do some transformations to the second table so that it looks like this:

[image: new format]

To do this, you'll have to transpose all columns, fill down the country column, and unpivot all other columns (highlight all other columns > unpivot columns). I'd then recommend adding a column to both tables that unites the country and sales location (USA-1st floor, USA-2nd floor, etc.) to both tables and use that as your connection in the model. You'll then be able to do a VLOOKUP using this united column between the tables.

Someone else may have a quicker answer but this should get you there!